# How to deal with answers based on the wrong system/edition?

Tags: discussion, answers, faq-proposal

I had recently seen and answered a question about [Silver Nitrate and werewolves/UV light and Vampires](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126057/would-uv-rounds-and-silver-nitrate-rounds-be-effective-on-vampires-werewolves) in *Werewolf the Apocalypse*/*Vampire the Masquerade*. I answered accordingly, but someone did answer using *Werewolf the Forsaken*/*Vampire the Requiem*. The rules difference couldn't be bigger unless you'd quote from the rules from *The Werewolves of Millers Hollow*. WoD and CoD1.0/CoD2.0 are in all regards totally different games with different backgrounds.

Now, I had around the same time asked [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102726/what-is-the-benefit-kitsune-have-over-other-fera-when-learning-gifts-not-on-thei) about the *Werewolf 20th Anniversary Edition* ruling on one topic, and yesterday someone answered with the correct ruling for *revised*. Yes, it is a correct answer for revised, but that was not what was asked for (W20 is the edition in question) and so is not only out of scope but what was written in the answer also was noted **and quoted** from the book in the OP.

So: What to do with an answer that, despite the game/edition been given in the question&tags, totally misses the point by quoting/referencing the wrong game/edition?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We should respond to these answers the same way we do to any other answer that is wrong or to any other "answer" post that doesn't actually answer the question:

- Since the answer is wrong, it should be downvoted for being unhelpful.
- Since the answer also doesn't answer the question that was asked (it instead answers a parallel universe version of the question), it should be flagged for deletion. *Note: To avoid confusion, the mod team prefers that you flag as "in need of moderator intervention" and explain that the answer is for the wrong system instead of just flagging as "not an answer."*

It's up to the author of the non-answer to fix their mistake, if they so choose, by editing the answer to rework it into compliance with the question or by deleting it, but neither action is compulsory.

Comment: Diamond moderators usually treat edition mismatch as Not An Answer and a reason for answer deletion, in alignment with what this answer's saying. For some games like GURPS edition mismatch hardly exists as a concept because of edition material being interchangeable, so we will not see any flags of that nature for those games. WoD seems like it is not one of those games.

Comment: However if you just flag NAA without leaving a comment or something and assume we're going to be expert in that game system enough to know what's going on, your flags are likely to be declined...

Comment: @mxyzplk Good call. I edited a note about that into my answer.

Comment: I was going to answer *burn them down*, but this alternative sounds good too.